# Function to get a weekday from a date in Python

Tags: python, function, date, if-statement, weekday

As part of a python tutorial, I've been trying to build a function that calculates the weekday from a given date. I know there's an easier way to do this but I really want to know why my function is not working. Whenever I enter a date, it returns None. I'd be grateful for any suggestions.
Here's the code:

```
# check if year is leap year: division by 4 possible, division by 100 impossible unless division by 400 possible
def isYearLeap(year):
    if year % 4 == 0:
        if year % 100 == 0:
            if year % 400 == 0:
                return True
            else:
                return False
        else:
            return True
    else:
        return False


# calculate days in each month
def daysInMonth(year, month):
    if month == 9 or month == 4 or month == 6 or month == 11:
        return 30
    elif month == 2:
        if isYearLeap(year):
            return 29
        else:
            return 28
    elif month == 1 or month == 3 or month == 5 or month == 7 or month == 8 or month == 10 or month == 12:
        return 31
    else:
        return False


# find out day of the year
def dayOfYear(year, month, day):
    century = year // 100
    # different rule for January and February because of leap years`enter code here`
    if month != 1 or month != 2:
        y = year % 100
        # Zeller's rule for calculating weekdays
        weekday = (day + (2.6 * (month - 2) - 0.2) - 2 * century + y + y / 4 + century / 4) % 7
        if weekday == 1:
            return "Sunday"
        elif weekday == 2:
            return "Monday"
        elif weekday == 3:
            return "Tuesday"
        elif weekday == 4:
            return "Wednesday"
        elif weekday == 5:
            return "Thursday"
        elif weekday == 6:
            return "Friday"
        elif weekday == 0:
            return "Saturday"
    else:
        y = (year % 100) - 1
        #Zeller's rule for calculating weekdays
        weekday = (day + (2.6 * (month + 10) - 0.2) - 2 * century + y + y / 4 + century / 4) % 7
        if weekday == 1:
            return "Sunday"
        elif weekday == 2:
            return "Monday"
        elif weekday == 3:
            return "Tuesday"
        elif weekday == 4:
            return "Wednesday"
        elif weekday == 5:
            return "Thursday"
        elif weekday == 6:
            return "Friday"
        elif weekday == 0:
            return "Saturday"


print(dayOfYear(2000, 12, 31))
print(dayOfYear(1980, 1, 4))
```

Comment: I think this is better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Not related to the cause of the problem but still: `if month != 1 or month != 2` condition is always `True`. Perhaps you meant `if month != 1 and month != 2`.

Comment: @Dani: no. Code Review is for working code, and it focuses on style and efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is on this line:

```
weekday = (day + (2.6 * (month - 2) - 0.2) - 2 * century + y + y / 4 + century / 4) % 7
```

The calculation returns a float value, but your if/elif statements check if the variable contains a specific integer value.

You could solve it by rounding the values to an int or and casting them to an int (you will have to check if the calculation is still correct after the conversion to integers):

```
weekday = int((day + (2.6 * (month - 2) - 0.2) - 2 * century + y + y / 4 + century / 4) % 7)
```

Comment: Thanks, I've rounded the values to int but I still get the wrong weekdays.

Comment: print(dayOfYear(2000, 12, 31)) returns Sunday which is correct
print(dayOfYear(1980, 1, 4)) returns Thursday though it should be Wednesday

Comment: Nevermind, I found the issue. I have to use // as the operator for the division.